# do pointers to classes increase modularity?

Tags: c++, class, pointers

I've noticed lately that when compiling large projects (I've been playing with the Audacity source), changing a file that is referenced by many other files, let's say a toolbar widget which is referenced in a couple dozen other files, causes compilation to take very long. If you need to tweak or debug a file like that it can take several minutes or longer to finish each compilation cycle.

If you would use pointers in the files that references the toolbar, would the compiler still need to recompile each files that contains a reference to the class?

If it doesn't, would it still compile those files by design?

Is it possible to have a pointer to a prototype of a class rather than to an instance, in any existing language or framework?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, but it depends how the files are sourced in the make file. If done properly with defined interfaces and factory classes, the other modules will only need to be rebuilt if you modify the interface header files. Modifying the module headers and/or source will thus not require a rebuild of modules.

Creating pointers will only work if the pointers are created through a factory that deals with the real instance creation and the pointer is an abstract interface type.

That said, you need to include the interface headers and modify the make files dependencies appropriately so they do not depend on the modules directly.

Answer (score 4):

Well, if you change an interface then there not much you can do; stuff has to be recompiled. However, if the code is designed using the [PIMPl design pattern](http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?PimplIdiom) then implementation changes usually don't cause a lot of recompiles.

Remember, even when working with pointers that the compiler usually needs to know the size of the object being pointed at. The PIMPL pattern hides the "real" object behind yet another pointer.

Comment: Is there a variation on this pattern that avoids the pointer indirection overhead? This is great stuff, but I don't see the point of sacrificing runtime performance for compilation speed. My gut feeling whispers there must me a preprocessor-based method to this.

Comment: @aelgoa: not that I know of. PIMPL does a lot more than just speed up compile time though. It also provides a cleaner source tree (my opinion) and really the overhead you are talking about is trivial, especially at the UI level.